# How to fix "Gtk-WARNING ** Content added to the action area of a dialog using header bars"

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I am getting this warning in terminal, if I have added buttons in GtkFileChooserDialog using Glade.

```
Gtk-WARNING ** Content added to the action area of a dialog using header bars
```

Program appears to work correctly even with that warning, however, I would like to fix warning.

[image]
How to fix this warning? What I am doing wrong?

Code bellow is simple GtkWindow with one button. When button will be clicked, it will open the dialog
There is example code how to replicate this problem:

C code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

//==============================================================Global=variables========================================================================
GtkWidget *FileChooserWindow; //Needed for file open dialog
//==================================Button=stuff==========================
void Button_clicked(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{
    g_print("Clicked\n");
    gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (FileChooserWindow));
}





int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "Resources/GUI_design.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    FileChooserWindow = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "FileChooserWindow"));
    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}




// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

Glade design code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkFileChooserDialog" id="FileChooserWindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="type_hint">dialog</property>
    <child internal-child="vbox">
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">2</property>
        <child internal-child="action_area">
          <object class="GtkButtonBox">
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="layout_style">end</property>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Click me</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_main">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">500</property>
    <property name="icon">icon.png</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_main_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="TestButton">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
        <signal name="clicked" handler="Button_clicked" swapped="no"/>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the ui archive and add a property in the dialog tree

To activate header bar:

```
<property name="use-header-bar"> 1 </property>
```

To deactivate header bar:

```
<property name="use-header-bar"> 0 </property>
```

Comment: That one worked for me, although I didn't find how to do it in Glade. I edited the .glade file and deactivated the header bar for all my dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not an error, your dialog will not crash everything.

GtkDialogs can either use or not use GtkHeaderBars. You can check it programmatically by checking [`"use-header-bar"`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialog--use-header-bar) property. If it's `TRUE`, you should [`get_header_bar`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-get-header-bar) and pack your buttons right there.

I don't know, how to do this with Glade. I'd suggest playing with different decorations checkboxes or writing code manually.

Comment: How I can add "use-header-bar" property?

Answer (score 0):

> Bumbieris112 : "How I can add "use-header-bar" property?"

Well pointing to the documentation (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialog.properties) a call like this should be enough:

```
g_object_set( dialog, "use-header-bar", 1, NULL );
```

But sadly it is not:

> ```
> (Dialog:2943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 23:57:00.433: g_object_set_is_valid_property: construct property "use-header-bar" for object 'GtkDialog' can't be set after construction
> ```

So in other words, based of this warning, once that you call `gtk_dialog_new()`  there is no way to set this properties anymore.

This means there are 2 possible ways to fix this kind of issue.

- 1)

Create a dialog-with-buttons

```
dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons( "response",
                                       window,
                                       GTK_DIALOG_USE_HEADER_BAR, /// Use this FLAG here
                                       "Yes", 1,
                                       "No", 2,
                                       "Cancel", 3,
                                       NULL );
```

- 2)

  You need to create it yourself:

  ```
  dialog = g_object_new ( GTK_TYPE_DIALOG,
             "transient-for", window,
             "use-header-bar", -1, /// Or 1 to not set it
             NULL );
  ```

If you need to check its default setting during the construction, then do:

```
gint use_header;
g_object_get ( gtk_settings_get_default (), "gtk-dialogs-use-header", &use_header, NULL );
g_print ( "use_header = %d\n", use_header );
```

And you will see that returns 0:

> use_header = 0

which is definitely not what the manual says:

> Flags: Read / Write / Construct Only Allowed values: [-1,1] Default
>   value: -1

So keep in mind that only `-1` to `1` are valid values.